# Deploying to App Engine within Eclipse (4.3) launches a browser - can I turn this off?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

Simple / Silly / Annoying thing, and I combed through all the preference menus to see if I could avoid this.

When I push an app-engine project to google's servers using the GAE plugin within eclipse (deploy to server...), upon successful push the plugin launches a web browser with that application's base URL. This is annoying, especially in this case as the doGet version of this application is kind of pointless.

Important data points: Eclipse 4.3, Appengine 1.8.5, plugins updated, system is Ububntu Linux 13.04